# Show that $\vec a \cdot \vec b = {1 \over 4} |\vec a + \vec b|^2 - {1 \over 4} |\vec a - \vec b|^2$

Tags: vectors

> Show that 
>   $$\vec a \cdot \vec b = {1 \over 4} |\vec a + \vec b|^2 - {1 \over 4} |\vec a - \vec b|^2$$

I have tried:

$$\vec a \cdot \vec b = {1 \over 4} |\vec a + \vec b|^2 - {1 \over 4} |\vec a - \vec b|^2
\\ \vec a \cdot \vec b = {1\over 4}(|\vec a|^2+2|\vec a||\vec b|+|\vec b|^2) - {1\over 4}(|\vec a|^2 -2|\vec a||\vec b|+|\vec b|^2)
\\ \vec a \cdot \vec b = |\vec a||\vec b|$$

However it seems that the equation only holds true when $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are collinear.

Is that true? Or did something go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your computation that $|a + b|^2 = a^2 + 2|a| |b| + |b|^2$ is wrong.

Comment: How would I do it instead? @T.Bongers

Comment: Write out what the definition of $|a + b|^2$ is. How did you come up with the formula in the first place?

Comment: I treated it as $(a+b)^2$. Which wouldn't work for the magnitude of vector...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Such formula is known as the Polarization Identity. Due to the inner product properties, we have:

\begin{align*}
\lVert\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}\rVert^{2} = \langle\textbf{a}+\textbf{b},\textbf{a}+\textbf{b}\rangle = \langle\textbf{a},\textbf{a}\rangle + 2\langle\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\rangle + \langle\textbf{b},\textbf{b}\rangle = \lVert\textbf{a}\rVert^{2} + 2\langle\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\rangle + \lVert\textbf{b}\rVert^{2}
\end{align*}

Analogously, we have

\begin{align*}
\lVert\textbf{a}-\textbf{b}\rVert^{2} = \langle\textbf{a}-\textbf{b},\textbf{a}-\textbf{b}\rangle = \langle\textbf{a},\textbf{a}\rangle - 2\langle\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\rangle + \langle\textbf{b},\textbf{b}\rangle = \lVert\textbf{a}\rVert^{2} - 2\langle\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\rangle + \lVert\textbf{b}\rVert^{2}
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?